# jQuery Roundabout: changing the number of items shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am using the jQuery Roundabout plugin.  I am wondering if there is a way to choose the number of pictures that are shown.  I have ten pictures, but only three of them should be visible as shown in the second (extention) link within the "square" example.

How is that possible?

Edit with further information:

jquery roundabout-plugin: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout

and extension: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout-shapes/

-> I would like to have the "square shape"

relevant code:

```
<head>
<style>
.roundabout-holder {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}

.roundabout-moveable-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  bottom: 0;
}

.roundabout-in-focus {
  cursor: auto;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.roundabout.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.roundabout-shapes.js"></script> 

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.roundabout-holder').roundabout({
         shape: 'square',
         btnNext: ".next",
         btnPrev: ".prev",
         btnStopAutoplay: ".stop",       
         btnStartAutoplay: ".start",                 
         duration: 1000,
         autoplay: true,
         autoplayDuration: 4000,         
         autoplayPauseOnHover: true,
         reflect: false,
         minOpacity: 0.5,
         minScale: 0.1
      });
   });
</script>  



</head>

<body>

<ul class="roundabout-holder">
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/hauptbild-gross.jpg"><img src="img/hauptbild.jpg" width="466" height="500" /></a></li>                
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/baerenfamilie-gross.jpg"><img src="img/baerenfamilie.jpg" width="400" height="196" /></a></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/hamster-bleistift-gross.jpg"><img src="img/hamster-bleistift.jpg" width="400" height="351" /></a></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/hamster-schlafend-gross.jpg"><img src="img/hamster-schlafend.jpg" width="400" height="302" /></a></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/hamster-schmetterling-gross.jpg"><img src="img/hamster-schmetterling.jpg" width="400" height="374" /></a></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"><a href="img/hase-gross.jpg"><img src="img/hase.jpg" width="384" height="500" /></a></li>
</ul>



</body>

</html>
```

---

And here is the project-url: 
http://www.eyes-on-fire.de/test/2/portfolio/tiere/index.php

(I wasn't allowed to post three links as a newbie)

Comment: Only three out of five are visible [here in the standard demo](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard), although I'm only guessing this is the same plugin you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, thats the right plugin, but in this example, there are 5 images visible.I've added further information above.

Comment: I would need this also... I have X images (whereby X is dynamic and almost larger as 50) and have to show only 3 images. Did you find a solution?

Comment: i need a help on this as well...i have 5 images, and i would like all of them to be viewable, in a scale and not only the three top.. i would really appreciate if anyone could get back with an answer

Answer (score -1):

Without going too much into detail:

```
maxScale: 1,
minScale: 0.7
```

should do the trick.

The idea is to adjust the `minScale` and `maxScale` according to your container width / height as applicable so that you see exactly the number of images / slides that you want to see.